# How to enable pinch-zoom in a cordova app under Android

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

Is there any clear/official guide for enabling pinch-zoom in an Android cordova app? I've read many posts about this, but was unable to get it working.
My cordova is 11.0.0 with android platform 10.1.1.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is indeed very helpful! But I am curious if there is a possibility to implement changing the font-size on pinch-zoom? I've seen it in one app...

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem using these steps:

1. I added the following meta tag within index.html

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`
```

2. Added these lines within the main Java file (platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/domainname/www/MainActivity.java)

- additional imports:

```java
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;`
```

- additional code after the loadUrl(launchUrl); line within the onCreate method:

```java
WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

The `setDisplayZoomControls()` method allows you to hide the native Webview zoom controls while pinch-zooming if you think they are annoying.

The above is working using:
Android API Level 30; cordova 11.0.0; cordova-android platform 10.1.1

Comment: This works perfectly also on cordova 9.1, android 10/11, thanks